# Image Gallery With Container Divs

Tags: jquery, css, html, gallery

Im trying to build a gallery like this with jquery:

[image]

I want to have a different background image in each container div, as well as a different image(img) in each div.

I also want the divs to fade in one after the other, as well as fade out when a new page is loaded.

How would i set this up?

Comment: @Willing learner , do you want a kind of guidence or really code , i can guide you how to do that if you want so ??

Comment: define a width for the div , and have fourd divs for a row , you can create a loop for this , have background image coming dynamically from a for loop and use jquery animate while adding background .., you should be knowing how to float the divs left right and clear..then you are all set.

Comment: I was kinda looking for the code to set this up, for i dont really know how.

Comment: I doubt that someone will just go ahead and write the whole gallery for you. But if you give us something you had tried, I'm sure people will be able to help you out. E.g. the HTML: Are all containers and all images of the same size?

Comment: I havent tried anything because I just dont know how i would go about setting this up to be generated dynamically.

Comment: It would be difficult to fade out your divs sequentially when a new page loads, unless you mean a page of images inside the gallery and not an entire new web page.

Answer (score 1):

You be best to use jQuery and use the fadeIn and fadeOut functions. You can string together the fadeIn functions so that after one has loaded it moves to the next one.

```
jQuery('#div1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
     jQuery('#div2').fadeIn('slow', function() { 
          //repeat for div3, div4, etc etc..
     }) 
});
```

Also, for the background images, you just give each div an id and set the background images via CSS:

```
#div1 {
  background-image: url(images/test.jpg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: none;
}
```

For the images inside the divs, just place them using HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <img src='test.jpg' width='100' height='100' alt="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there a more dynamic way to build this with jquery? Lets say I wish to have a grid of 300 divs... I highly doubt It would be efficient writing jQuery('#div1').fadeIn('slow', function() {  300 times.

Comment: @WillingLearner you could use the setTimeout function and create a loop.
`code`
setTimeout("showDiv()", 5000);

var counter = 0;

function showDiv() {
    jQuery('#div'+counter).fadeIn('slow');
    counter++;
}